# R metadata csw harvest gdalutils

Tags: r, metadata, gdal, rvest, rgdal

I am looking to harvest the content of a metadata catalogue like this one :

http://csw.data.gov.uk/geonetwork/srv/en/csw

The catalogue contains metadata on (open geographical) datasets and services.

I have looked into using the rgdal/gdalUtils packages, but to no avail. I feel i am missing something really basic, can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: The URL you are pointing to only shows `MissingParameterValue`... Can you please show expected output and possibly the code you tried to get there so far

Comment: @Floo0 Thank you for your reply! You can see the output using this approach : [link](http://csw.data.gov.uk/geonetwork/srv/en/csw?service=CSW&version=2.0.2&request=GetRecords&namespace=xmlns%28csw=http://www.opengis.net/cat/csw%29&resultType=results&outputSchema=http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd&outputFormat=application/xml&maxRecords=20&elementSetName=full&constraintLanguage=CQL_TEXT&&constraint_language_version=1.1.0&typeNames=any&constraint=AnyText%20like%20%27INSPIRE%27)

Comment: The problem i face is how to loop & parse over the 20 xml replies I  get at a time  ... but that's for the holidays!